# Create Directory using Get-Date is making Sub Folders?

Tags: powershell

Just a small issue and i'm likely missing something very simple 
I've setup a script just to make a few folders as part of a bigger script 
I've tried to set it up so that when the script is ran a new directory is created with the date in as so:

```
$Date = ((Get-Date).ToShortDateString())
$CompileFolder = "C:\Registry_Export\PostInfection\$Date\Compiled Postinfection"
New-Item -path $CompileFolder -ItemType Directory
```

The script works as intended (The part above is just a piece from the script)
However when the directories are generated they are creating sub directories instead of just one directory.

For Example 23/03/2017 should make a folder called 23/03/2017 
However it is making a folder structure of:

C:\Registry_Export\PostInfection\23\03\2017\Compiled Postinfection 
I understand that this is because of the / that is generated because of the date however would like to know if there is an easy way to rectify this

Thank You

Comment: `/` is an illegal file name character in NTFS (and, by extension, also an illegal directory name character). When you say "rectify", what do you mean/want/expect?

Comment: Ah yeah why didn't I think of that I got too focused on the DIR being made.  Is there a way I could change / to . so 23/03/2017 turns to 23.03.2017

Comment: See the answer I posted

Comment: `Get-Date -Format "dd.MM.yyyy"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/` is an illegal file name character in NTFS (and, by extension, also an illegal directory name character).

I would suggest either using a different separator for your date string, like `-` or `.`, or just omitting a separator completely. To use a custom format, you can use either [`ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx), the [`-f` string format operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#special-operators), or `Get-Date -Format`

```
# using hyphens (23-07-2017)
$Date = '{0:dd-MM-yyyy}' -f (Get-Date)

# using dots (23.07.2017)
$Date = (Get-Date).ToString('dd.MM.yyyy')

# using no separator (23072017)
$Date = Get-Date -Format ddMMyyyy
```

Comment: Thank you, Something so simple to fix the issue, you forget the little things

Answer (score 1):

To complement [Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42988221/45375):

Another way of putting it: any `\` *or* `/` chars. in a name passed to `New-Item -ItemType Directory` are interpreted as *path separators* separating *multiple* directory names.

Generally, consider using a *culture-invariant*, *sortable* string format, such as the one provided by the [`s` standard format string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.sortabledatetimepattern(v=vs.110).aspx), which is based on the ISO 8601 standard:

```
> (Get-Date -Format s) -replace 'T.*'
2017-03-23
```

The `-replace 'T.*'` part simply cuts off the time portion.